# Formatting rules for numbers in KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

I have a viewModel with a bunch of numbers with lots of decimal places.  If my bindings look like this:

```
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Date"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: ActualWeight"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: TrendWeight"></td>
    </tr>
```

Then, of course, the output has all the decimal places and is very unreadable.  Changing the bindings to look like this solves the problem, but is very verbose and "noisy":

```
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Date"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: ActualWeight().toFixed(1)"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: TrendWeight().toFixed(1)"></td>
    </tr>
```

Note, this is one small snippet and having to add .toFixed(1) every place I bind a number leads to much more messy markup than what is shown here.

For everything except numbers, overriding the toString has been an effective way for me to control what the output looks like.  Any suggestions on a way to tell knockout once, in some central way for my page what function to use to convert numbers into strings before they are added to the output?

For that matter, having a general purpose way to tell knockout how to format any type of value seems like it would be useful.  Overriding Date.prototype.toString works but feels a little heavy handed since it may impact other uses of .toString besides just knockout's.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

There are a couple of ways that you can handle a situation like this one.  You can either choose to address it through bindings or push it into your view model.

If your view model is created by the mapping plugin and you don't want to get into customizing the way that it is created, then you can consider using a custom binding that is a wrapper to the text binding to handle the formatting.

Something like (http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/RVL6q/):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.numericText = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
       var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
           precision = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().precision) || ko.bindingHandlers.numericText.defaultPrecision,
           formattedValue = value.toFixed(precision);

        ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function() { return formattedValue; });
    },
    defaultPrecision: 1  
};
```

It certainly would be possible to create an even more generic binding (formattedText) that either inspected the value and formatted it using some overridable defaults or allowed you to pass in some formatting options (`{ type: "numeric", precision: 2 }`).

For your scenario, it sounds like the first option might be a good choice.  However, if you want to push it into your view model, then you could create a special observable that can return both a formatted and a raw version of the value.

It could be something like (http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/fetBG/):

```
function formattedNumericObservable(initialValue, precision) {
    var _raw = ko.observable(initialValue),
        precision = precision || formattedNumericObservable.defaultPrecision,        
        //the dependentObservable that we will return
        result = ko.dependentObservable({
            read: function() {
               return _raw().toFixed(precision); 
            },
            write: _raw
        });

        //expose raw value for binding
        result.raw = _raw;

        return result;   
}
```

Now you could potentially bind against `myValue` and `myValue.raw` depending on your needs.  Otherwise, you could flip it and return the raw value by default and expose a `formatted` dependentObservable. When an object like this is converted to JSON, it will lose any of the "sub-observables", so if you are sending this data back to a server that might be a consideration.

You could again make it more generic and create a `formattedObservable` that takes in some information about how to format the object.

Finally, 1.3 beta offers an `extenders` API.  You could do something similar to above like: (http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/AsdES/)

```
ko.extenders.numeric = function(target, precision) {
    var result = ko.dependentObservable({
        read: function() {
           return target().toFixed(precision); 
        },
        write: target 
    });

    result.raw = target;
    return result;
};
```

Then, apply it to an observable like: `var myValue = ko.observable(1.223123).extend({numeric: 1});`

You could have the extender also just add a `formatted` dependentObservable to `target` instead of returning the dependentObservable itself.

Answer (score 22):

Since knockout now supports [extenders](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html), I would use them instead of custom bindings. The binding would look something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td data-bind="text: Date.extend({format : 'date'})"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: ActualWeight.extend({format : 'weight'})"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: TrendWeight.extend({format : 'weight'})"></td>
</tr>
```

You have to write the `format` extender in this case. Examples are provided in the knockout documentation.

Comment: This seems like the right direction but an example would be nice

Comment: You'd extend them in the viewmodel rather than view.

Comment: Actually, for consistency across app viewmodel, but for designers to have easy access and flexibility, this view markup makes sense. Although doesn't play well with Durandal.

Answer (score 10):

To format currency and percent I have created my custom binding numeralformat.js to be used with numeral.min.js found at http://adamwdraper.github.com/Numeral-js/

numeralformat.js (Inspired by dateformat.js and moment.min.js)

```
var formatNumber = function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, format) {
    // Provide a custom text value
    var value = valueAccessor(), allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
    var numeralFormat = allBindingsAccessor.numeralFormat || format;
    var strNumber = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
    if (strNumber) {
        return numeral(strNumber).format(numeralFormat);
    }
    return '';
};

ko.bindingHandlers.numeraltext = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        $(element).text(formatNumber(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, "(0,0.00)"));  
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        $(element).text(formatNumber(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, "(0,0.00)"));
    }
};

ko.bindingHandlers.numeralvalue = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        $(element).val(formatNumber(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, "(0,0.00)"));

        //handle the field changing
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($(element).val());
        });        
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        $(element).val(formatNumber(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, "(0,0.00)"));
    }
};

ko.bindingHandlers.percenttext = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        $(element).text(formatNumber(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, "(0.000 %)"));
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        $(element).text(formatNumber(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, "(0.000 %)"));
    }
};

ko.bindingHandlers.percentvalue = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        $(element).val(formatNumber(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, "(0.000 %)"));

        //handle the field changing
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($(element).val());
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        $(element).val(formatNumber(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, "(0.000 %)"));
    }
};
```

Examples of bindings in View.

```
        <td><label>Available Commitment Balance:</label> </td>
        <td>
            <!-- ko with: SelectedLoan -->
            <span data-bind="numeraltext: AvailableCommitmentAmount"></span>            
            <!-- /ko -->
        </td>
        <td><label> % Interest Rate:</label></td>
        <td>
            <!-- ko with: SelectedLoan -->
            <input  data-bind="percentvalue: InterestRatePercent" />
            <!-- /ko -->
        </td>
        <td><label> $ Amount To Transfer:</label></td>
        <td>
            <!-- ko with: SelectedLoan -->
            <input class="inputsmall" data-bind="numeralvalue: FundsHeldTotalAmount" />
            <!-- /ko -->
        </td>
```

Answer (score 9):

To build upon the accepted answer above. I forked RP Niemeyers fiddle to add comma formatting as well. 
So, if you have 10001.232 this will format as 10,001.232.  Pretty important if you're working with prices.  Again, this is just building on the answer.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stephenzr/Lqzv6/4/)

```
<div data-bind="numericText: myValue"></div>
<div data-bind="numericText: myValue, positions: 3"></div>
<div data-bind="numericText: myValue, positions: myPositions"></div>
<input data-bind="value: myPositions" />

<div>
    <br>
    just testing commas<br>
    <input type=text id="withComma" readonly/>
</div>
```

```
ko.bindingHandlers.numericText = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
       var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
       var positions= ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().positions) || ko.bindingHandlers.numericText.defaultPositions;
       var formattedValue = value.toFixed(positions); 
       var finalFormatted = ko.bindingHandlers.numericText.withCommas(formattedValue);  

        ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function() { return finalFormatted ; });
    },

    defaultPositions: 2,

    withCommas: function(original){
       original+= '';
     x = original.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;

    } 
};

var viewModel = {
    myValue: ko.observable(12673.554),
    myPositions: ko.observable(4)
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

/*Just testing the function below, you don't need thsi....*/     



function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
var formatted = addCommas('1070781.493')
$('#withComma').val(formatted);
```

Answer (score 2):

I approached formatting using jQuery Globalize plug-in.
Here is my version of formatting handlers, `textFormatted` and `valueFormatted` are wrappers for text and value bindings respectively.

Usage will be:

```
<span data-bind="textFormatted: Amount, pattern: 'n'" />
```

Optionally, culture can be specified as well. But I think this kind of control should not belong to HTML, although it can be helpful during developing or debugging time...

```
<input data-bind="valueFormatted: Amount, pattern: 'n', culture: 'et'" type="text" />
```

Values for `pattern` property/binding must be any of suitable formats that 
`Globalize.format( value, format, [locale] )` function's `format` param expects.
Same goes for `culture` property/binding that will be used in optional `locale` param.
[Globalize reference.](https://github.com/jquery/globalize#globalizeformat-value-format-locale-)

Binding definitions:

```
(function() {

    function getFormatedOrPlainResult(value, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var pattern = allBindingsAccessor.get('pattern');

        if (pattern == null || !/\S*/.test(pattern)) {
            return value;
        }
        var valueToFormat = pattern === 'd' ? new Date(value) : value;
        return Globalize.format(valueToFormat, pattern, allBindingsAccessor.get('culture'));
    };

    ko.bindingHandlers.textFormatted = {
        init: ko.bindingHandlers.text.init,
        update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            var result = getFormatedOrPlainResult(ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()), allBindingsAccessor);
            ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function() { return result; });
        }
    };

    ko.bindingHandlers.valueFormatted = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            var result = getFormatedOrPlainResult(ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()), allBindingsAccessor);
            ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, function() { return result; }, allBindingsAccessor);
        },
        update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            var result = getFormatedOrPlainResult(ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()), allBindingsAccessor);
            ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, function() { return result; }, allBindingsAccessor);
        }
    };
}());
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's just about displaying a localized number of a text binding, a very easy way is to use `toLocaleString()`

```
<tr>
  <td data-bind="text: ActualWeight().toLocaleString()"></td>
  <td data-bind="text: TrendWeight().toLocaleString()"></td>
</tr>
```

For more information visit [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

Answer (score 0):

Let's make it simpler.  MUCH simpler:

The keyword is unwrap, and note the parenthesis after amount. (This doesn't have to be part of your knockout object.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getDecimal(amount) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(amount());
        return parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
    }
...

<span data-bind="text: getDecimal(ItemAmount)">
```

Alternatively, you DON'T have to unwrap it if you do this instead (notice the parenthesis):

```
function getDecimal(amount) {
    return parseFloat(amount).toFixed(2);
}
<span data-bind="text: getDecimal(ItemAmount())">
```