# Knockout extender or binding?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm new to Knockout and am looking to format the output of computed fields. Specifically, currency and percentages. I've seen some examples using custom binding as well as extenders. I gather that extenders are the newer concept of the two. Does that mean extenders are the RIGHT choice for my needs? I can't find any definitive answers on this.

I also can't find any resources that have any standard formatting binding/extenders already built. Do I really have to reinvent the wheel on this? Seems very odd that nothing is already out there... Or is there a better approach to formatting KO computed?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you can use either a custom binding or an extension/extender to do formatting. It comes down to whether you want the logic to be enforced at the view model level or in the view itself as a binding.

Putting it in the view model ensures that values changed via the UI or programmatically will all hit the formatting logic. So, it is reliable, but can complicate the view model (especially if it is created by something like the mapping plugin).

Putting it in a binding, simplifies the view model, while being effective for most use cases (where programmatic changes to a value are not a concern).

This is an older answer, but demonstrates both: [Formatting rules for numbers in KnockoutJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704268/formatting-rules-for-numbers-in-knockoutjs/7705174#7705174).