# Format knockout observable with commas and/or decimal places within html data binding, NOT in viewmodel

Tags: knockout.js

I've seen RP Niemeyer's answer here: [Formatting rules for numbers in KnockoutJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704268/formatting-rules-for-numbers-in-knockoutjs) but it doesn't seem to fit my situation.

My viewmodel is tightly bound with breeze entities for a start, so I cannot easily mess with the individual table fields.  There are c. 40 fields that contain numerical impact calculation results, often to 9 or 10 decimal places. It is essential that the raw result is left untouched in the viewmodel.

RP Niemeyer's "extend" based solution seems to suit more a situation where the observable is manually created. I'd like to be able to do the formatting within the html data-bind itself as this allows me to leave things untouched in the database and just limit the display of the calculation to 3 or 4 decimal places.

I'd like to be able to do:

```
<div data-bind="text: myValue, precision: 1"></div>
```

using the extend model such as this if possible?

```
ko.extenders.numeric = function(target, precision) {
    var result = target;

    result.formatted = ko.dependentObservable({
        read: function() {
           return target().toFixed(precision); 
        },
        write: target 
    });

    return result.formatted;
};
```

but as it is, this currently doesn't work so I'm probably missing something really obvious.

Comment: does something like the `numericText` binding from the answer that you linked work for you?  It is an alternative to the extender.

Comment: Perfectly :-)  I think I got a bit anxious by the comments saying, "you should be using an extender now..." in other comments on that question.  Presumably the `numericText` binding is still perfectly valid to be using?  Also, this is leaving my underlying value alone, isn't it?  It's just the display value that's being formatted?

Comment: yes- good alternative when you don't want to or can't conveniently manipulate the creation of the observables on your view model.

Comment: That's great, thanks for the help. Pop up a link to the question I referenced as an answer, maybe?  Along with your comment about it being useful when you can't manipulate the observables easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer: [Formatting rules for numbers in KnockoutJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704268/formatting-rules-for-numbers-in-knockoutjs) contains a `numericText` binding that might work in your scenario.

Using a binding is definitely helpful in scenarios where it is not easy or convenient to hook into the creation of the observables/properties of your view model.