# knockout js fomat text using a binding handler

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using knockout js along with `ko.mapping` to map my server side view models to the client. In my server side view model I have a decimal property that I am trying to display with a comma instead of a dot on the ui.

I have a looked at few threads and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704268/formatting-rules-for-numbers-in-knockoutjs), it has [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/RVL6q/).

```
ko.bindingHandlers.numericText = {
update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
   var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
       precision = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().precision) || ko.bindingHandlers.numericText.defaultPrecision,
       formattedValue = value.toFixed(precision);

    ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function() { return formattedValue; });
},
defaultPrecision: 1  
};
```

The difference between what the fiddle shows and my scenario is I am trying to display the value in a text box, while the fiddle only displays in a div.

To test I have everything in place I have successfully bound the values to a div.
I have also tried changing

`ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function() { return formattedValue; });`

to

`ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, function() { return formattedValue; });`

**the rest of my code**

```
<input class="form-control" id="txtDisplayFrom" data-bind="numericText: DisplayFrom" placeholder="Display From" type="text">

var vm = function (data) {
           var self = this;
           ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
           ...other stuff
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modified the fiddle you posted: http://jsfiddle.net/RVL6q/553/
Is that what you're after?

Fiddle code below:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.numericText = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
       var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
           precision = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().precision) || ko.bindingHandlers.numericText.defaultPrecision,
           formattedValue = value.toFixed(precision);

        ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function() { return formattedValue; });
        ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, function() { return formattedValue.replace('.',','); });


    },
    defaultPrecision: 2  
};


var viewModel = {
    myValue: ko.observable(123.55454),
    myPrecision: ko.observable(4)
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but I not get the following error `Unable to process binding "numericText: function (){return DisplayFrom }"`

Comment: @tony09uk, can you post your code which is giving the error? Can't debug errors without the source code!