# Regex to replace strings inside of JSON Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

The structure of the JSON Object is as follows:

```
{
 "headings": [
   "A",
   "B",
   "C"
 ],
 "results": [
  {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Unknown",
   "number1": 12000,
   "number2": 20000
  },
  {
   "id": 2,
   "name": "Unknown2",
   "number1": 12000,
   "number2": 20000
  }
 ]
}
```

My AJAX which gets the data looks like this:

```
var myChart= [];

/*Knockout.js*/
var viewModel = {
    myChartData: ko.observable()
};

$.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: myAPI,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            myChart[0] = data.results;
            viewModel.myChartData(myChart[0]);
        }
    });
```

A little bit of background information the reason the data is going into a blank array is because i have a table with a button next to it that allows you to swap between data. So there is another AJAX which is pretty much the same as this one but is being inserted into myChart[1].

Now I'm using KnockoutJS to foreach through the data in the HTML like:

```
<tbody id="topretailers" data-bind="foreach: leftChartData">
 <tr>
  <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
  <td data-bind="text: number1"></td>
  <td data-bind="text: number2"></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

I would like to add a delimiter to the numbers e.g (12,000). However i ideally want to do this before it goes into the knockout observable so I can still use the foreach.

I have the regex `.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")` ready to use but I don't know the best way to do this.

Is there a way of replacing all number1's and nummber2's throughout the results object? Without having to create a new object?

So eventually the table will look like:

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Number 1</th>
    <th>Number 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Unknown</td>
    <td>12,000</td>
    <td>20,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Unknown2</td>
    <td>12,000</td>
    <td>20,000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Relevant question : [Formatting rules for numbers in KnockoutJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704268/formatting-rules-for-numbers-in-knockoutjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
// This is data.results here
// coming from ajax request
var results = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Unknown",
    "number1": 12000,
    "number2": 20000
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Unknown2",
    "number1": 14000,
    "number2": 25000
  }
];

// Loop over results array and update the key values
for (var i = 0; i< results.length; i++) {
    results[i].number1 = results[i].number1.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    results[i].number2 = results[i].number2.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
}

console.log(results)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I encountered an error - "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined"

Comment: In `data.results` array doesn't that have objects with `number1` and `number2` keys? or in few objects these keys are missing?

Comment: My Mistake, I adjusted the JSON object for the purposes of the question and forgot to change it back in my code. All works perfectly thank you!