# how to round a number with knoukout?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a number for the 'weight' that is displayed like below, and I want to round it with knockoutjs :

```
3.0000
```

and i want it like this :

```
3
```

this is the code :

```
                        <strong class="product-item-name">
                            <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
                            <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, html: product_weight"></a>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
                            <!-- ko text: product_weight --><!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </strong>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting rules for numbers in KnockoutJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704268/formatting-rules-for-numbers-in-knockoutjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need knockout to do your rounding. Math.round (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) will do what you want. You can call javascript functions or any other function that's in scope in your binding. Think in your case that would be something like:

```
<--ko text: Math.round(product_weight()) -->
```

You can hang functions off of your view model too and call them in your bindings like so:

```
var myViewModel {
  myViewProperty: ko.observable("a value"),
  myRoundingFunction: function(v) {
    return Math.round(v);
  }
}
```

And then do:

```
<div data-bind="text:myCoolFunction(myViewProperty)"></div>
```

Which will call the function in your view model on the property `myViewProperty` that is in the view model.

Comment: Make sure to unwrap the observable value before passing it to `round`! (i.e. `myFn(myProp())` or `Math.round(v())`)

Comment: @user3297291 good catch. Edit made. It illustrates a knockout fundamental concept: when you're using an observable in an expression like in Math.round you need to "unwrap" it which means you have to call it as a function to get the underlying value. In contrast, the example with myViewProperty is passing the observable into another observable inside of the binding which doesn't require the unwrapping. The binding does it for you. A good reference for this is here: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/06/10-things-to-know-about-knockoutjs-on.html.

Comment: Knockout unwraps the whole expression of your binding, not the individually referenced observables. I.e.: `ko.unwrap(myFn(myProp))`. This is **not** equivalent to `myFn(ko.unwrap(myProp))`. Therefore, even in your second example, you have to manually unwrap using `()` or `ko.unwrap`. I sometimes wish they skipped this auto unwrapping, cause it confuses many people.

Comment: Agreed @user3297291. My statement "the binding does it for you" implies that you wouldn't need to unwrap myViewProperty in the body of myCoolFunction if you pass myViewProperty in as an argument. But you *would* have to unwrap it if you wanted to use the value of myViewProperty in the function since it's still an observable. The "auto unwrapping" would only happen if you did something like text:myViewProperty.